# how do i span multiple lines text in java miglayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, miglayout

i am using miglayout in java. I would like to know how do i make a very long text in a jlabel span multiple lines if that text exceeds width of container? please help. i cannot use html it makes painting slow

Comment: use a textArea instead of the label - or JXLabel of the SwingX project, though it has its quirks - a plain label doesn't support line wraps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
JPanel jpanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0 0 0 0", "[fill, 99%]", "[grow]"));
```

I found thisin my code and its working fine. I think "[grow]" is responsible for making this work.

Comment: probably not: the question is "label span multiple **lines** if that text exceeds **width** of container" ...

Comment: smajlo i have different kinds of jcomponents, buttons jlist, etc in the same panel and as far as i know fill 99% is telling all components, not just label alone, to fill 99%. definitely not what i want